# How can I join strings that are inside of an element of a multidimensional list?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have a multidimensional list with strings inside it's elements. For example:

```
list = [['blur', 'ccd', 'damage', 'jack', 'flare', 'reason'],
        ['jump', 'everyone'],
        ['sadness', 'sick', 'joy']]
```

And I want join these strings into one element. Something like:

```
list = [['blur ccd damage jack flare reason'],
        ['jump everyone'],
        ['sadness sick joy']]
```

I am trying with an for loop, but I get some errors or unexpected results.

Comment: Probably better if the result is `[s1, s2, s3]` rather than `[[s1], [s2], [s3]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is a list comprehension with `str.join`:

```
>>> my_list = [['blur', 'ccd', 'damage', 'jack', 'flare', 'reason'],
...         ['jump', 'everyone'],
...         ['sadness', 'sick', 'joy']]
>>> [' '.join(x) for x in my_list]
['blur ccd damage jack flare reason', 'jump everyone', 'sadness sick joy']
>>> [[' '.join(x)] for x in my_list]
[['blur ccd damage jack flare reason'], ['jump everyone'], ['sadness sick joy']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that :

```
list = [['blur', 'ccd', 'damage', 'jack', 'flare', 'reason'],
        ['jump', 'everyone'],
        ['sadness', 'sick', 'joy']]
      

for smallerList in list:
   combinedWord = ""
   for word in smallerList:
      combinedWord+= word+ " "
   smallerList.clear()
   smallerList.append(combinedWord)
   # print(smallerList)
print(list)
```

Comment: I hope it helped